# why are Perl::Unsafe::Signals and LWPx::ParanoidAgent giving me a seg fault?

Tags: perl

I am running a scraper that is fetching some key pieces of information from several hundred webpages. Everything is mostly working fine, but on timeouts I am getting a segmentation fault.

```
use Perl::Unsafe::Signals;
require LWPx::ParanoidAgent;
...
$ua = LWPx::ParanoidAgent->new();
$ua->timeout(60);
...
local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
    print "Timeout occurred.  Skipping to next record.\n";
};
alarm 60; # give each journal a minute to respond, in total.
UNSAFE_SIGNALS {
    ...
    # some calls like the following: 
    my $pageResponse = $ua->get($url);
    if ($pageResponse->is_success) {
        # calls to a sub
        # that also does $ua->get()
        # I think it fails inside the sub (if that makes a diff)
    }
};
alarm 0; # clear the timeout.
```

Running: perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for i686-linux

The script is throwing the segmentation fault after a timeout. I get the print for "timeout ocured" and then Segmentation Fault.

Does anybody have any clues as to what might be happening? Suggestions for debugging?

Extra Info: 
I had just an "eval" block, instead of an UNSAFE_SIGNALS block before and it would just hang when a timeout occurred.

Comment: Unsafe signals is almost certainly your issue.  Have you considered combining threads & safe (default) signals?

Comment: Or perhaps an event loop? (threads suck in perl, and alarm isn't terribly portable anyway.) https://socialtext.net/perl5/concurrency

Comment: Use LWP's `timeout` argument. LWP uses `alarm` internally, IIRC

Comment: @tjd: have a quick example?

Comment: @ikegami: I do set it: $ua->timeout(25);

Comment: Listen to ikegami.  But if you're very currious, check out http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html#THREAD-SIGNALLING

Comment: So your question is why doesn't `timeout` do anything for you? What troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: I am now looking into how timeout is supposed to work. I didn't write the script originally, and the timeout is there at the top, but the script also has the alarm. Are these two conflicting with one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by putting the eval block only around the $ua->get request, and nothing else. It seems the problem was with reaching an inconsistent state depending on when the alarm was triggered.

Used the following code for all my get requests:

```
sub uaGetWrapper($) {
    my $url = shift;
    my $response;
    eval {
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "timeout"; };
        alarm 60;
        $response = $ua->get($url);
        alarm 0;
    };

    if ($@ && $@ =~ /timeout/) {
        return 0; # return false on a timeout.
    }

    return $response;
}
```